# How to insert a file, server-side, into images, fs.files and fs.chunks -GridFS (Ostrio/files)

Tags: meteor, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am using Ostrio/files also known as meteor-files (from VeliovGroup or keenethics) on the server-side to insert a file to db.images, db.fs.files and db.fs.chunks. My code only manages to insert a record only in db.images and nothing on fs.files and fs.chunks. My code is as follows:

```js
Images.write(this.bodyParams.file, {
  fileName: 'SignUpTermsAndConditions_' + this.bodyParams.name,
  fielId: 'abc123myId', //optional
  type: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
  meta: {owner: this.userId,createdAt: new Date()}
}, function (error, fileRef) {
  if (error) {
 throw error;
  } else {
 console.log(fileRef.name + ' is successfully saved to FS. _id: ' + fileRef._id);
  }
});
```

I am able to insert a file from the client into db.images, db.fs.files and db.fs.chunks using the following code:

```js
Images.insert({
 file: file,  // where var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
 fileName: fileName + e.currentTarget.files[0].name,
 onStart: function () {
 },
 onUploaded: function (error, fileObj) {
   if (error) {
  alert('Error during upload: ' + error);
   } else {
   }
 },
 streams: 'dynamic',
 chunkSize: 'dynamic'
});
```

The server code as per the first snippet above is one that is not working correctly or as expected.Please help.

For info: how I setup my gridFS is as per 
[this link](https://github.com/keenethics/Meteor-Files/blob/c282bd2a58ad8d235020aa821434012382233edb/docs/gridfs.md#final-result). My Images.write as per my second code snippet above is as per the code in
[this link](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Write). In short I am following the documentation but my server Images.write is not working as expected.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I set the fourth parameter to true i.e proceedAfterUpload=true and records are inserted in db.fs.files and db.fs.chunks. This is as per the [write method documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Write), it is slightly vague though. Here is the amended code:

```js
Images.write(this.bodyParams.file, {
  fileName: 'SignUpTermsAndConditions_' + this.bodyParams.name,
  fielId: 'abc123myId', //optional
  type: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
  meta: {owner: this.userId,createdAt: new Date()}
}, function (error, fileRef) {
  if (error) {
 throw error;
  } else {
 console.log(fileRef.name + ' is successfully saved to FS. _id: ' + fileRef._id);
  }
},proceedAfterUpload=true);
```

That's it.

PS: Make sure this.bodyParams.file is a buffer so that the inserted file is not corrupt - thanks to @dr.dimitru for advising me on inserting a buffer.